# Counting number of points in a point shapefile - ArcGIS 10.0 / arcpy

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I assumed this would be an easy thing to do. I'm loading a point shapefile into a map like this:

```
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(file_name)
```

Is there a way to get the number of points in the shapefile? I see using the 'Describe' command that I can get some info about things... For instance,

```
arcpy.Describe(layer).table.fields
```

Gives me some info about the fields in the underlying table but I can't count the rows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `int(arcpy.GetCount_management(layer).getOutput(0))`: [here's the documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-count.htm).